# Quantum tunneling and continuity of solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am stuck on a "paradox". Say a 1-D quantum wave with energy E is traveling to the right, reaching a potential step where potential energy increases from $0$ to $U_0$.

$$U = \begin{cases}0 & x<0 \\\\ 
U_0 & x>0\end{cases}$$

If $U_0 < E$, the wave will continue oscillating with energy $E - U_0$; if $U_0 > E$, then the wave will exponentially decay until it reaches a region with a low potential barrier and become oscillating again.

The problem is regarding the continuous change of $U_0$. Let $dE$ be a  very small amount of energy. Then, if $U_0 = E - dE$, the wave after entering the potential barrier will oscillate with energy $dE$, which means it nearly vanishes; however, if $U_0 = E + dE$, then the wave after entering the potential barrier will decay exponentially. In particular, if $dx$ is some small positive amount of distance, the probability density at $0+dx$ will almost not decay. Therefore, as $U_0$ increase from $E-dE$ to $E +dE$, the probability density $|\Psi|^2$ at $0+dx$ discontinuously jumps from almost zero to a positive amount.

Why is there a discontinuity? Is there a problem with my reasoning?

Comment: Is there is discontinuity? Your description sounds good for transmittance and absorption, but have you included reflection? You need to solve the problem and match the boundary conditions at barrier.

Comment: Thank you. I will solve the problem and try to find the loophole in my previous reasoning.